# Create a new rdd replacing value with another

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new here and a I didn't see in other questions what I'm looking for. It's simple, I know how to do in a dataframe, but not in a RDD. I have one RDD and of course I want a new RDD replacing only one attribute (not all the attributes from the file). This attribute is string and it need to be integer. The question is how can I change 'M' with 1 and 'F' with 0. For example, the data are:

```
    ...
    StructField("UserID", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Gender", StringType(), True)
    ...

    print(Users_Rdd)
    [u'1::F', u'2::M', u'3::M', u'4::M', u'5::M']
```

And I need:

```
    print(new_Users_Rdd)
    [u'1::0', u'2::1', u'3::0', u'4::1', u'5::1']
```

Thanks!!

Comment: python approach a little different to scala, but not insurmountable

Answer (score 1):

Not 100%, but the guiding principles and an approach evident.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("abc", "M"), ("defg", "M"), ("cc", "F")))
val rdd2 = rdd.map{ case (field1, field2) => (field1, if (field2 == "M") 1 else 0) }.collect
```

Returns:

```
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at command-4459844623723459:1
rdd2: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((abc,1), (defg,1), (cc,0))
```

Collect only used if required, otherwise omit. You can adapt as stated.